# Why does MPI give run time Error

Tags: linux, message

After i typed

```
sudo apt-get install mpich2
```

The mpich was installed but the first problem is that I dont know where the files were installed. On the other hand when I wrote

```
mpirun -np 3 ./hello.o
```

it gives me:

```
mpiexec_hani-laptop: cannot connect to local mpd (/tmp/mpd2.console_hani); possible causes:
  1. no mpd is running on this host
  2. an mpd is running but was started without a "console" (-n option)
In case 1, you can start an mpd on this host with:
    mpd &
and you will be able to run jobs just on this host.
For more details on starting mpds on a set of hosts, see
the MPICH2 Installation Guide.
```

Can any one help.

Comment: dpkg -L mpich2  will show you where the files are.  There are a few front-ends to apt/dpkg that try to collect up all the different commands you need to do various things into one front-end.  e.g. wajig.

Answer (score 6):

Probably because the mpd (Multi- Purpose Daemon) is not running like it says. "Hydra" is another one of the popularly used process management system for parallel processes.
Try this :

```
mpd &
```

or this :

```
mpiexec.hydra -np 3 ./hello.o
```

These daemons are used for scheduling processes to the required cores.
Note: After running the above command once, mpirun also seems to work without issues.

Comment: This helped me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to add a line to my script exporting some libs:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mpich2-1.0.5p4/lib:/usr/local/hdf5/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out where `mpirun` is by typing `which mpirun` (this works for any command).  The `mpd` issue sounds like it might be that you need to be running an mpi daemon before you run anything. I have not used mpich, but I recall my advisor mentioning that this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

mpich2 uses mpd as a job scheduler. That means the mpd daemon has to be running before you can run MPI jobs.

In addition, to get mpd running correctly across multiple nodes, you will need to configure them all with matching passwords (or "secretkey", I can't remember which term mpich2 uses.)

Is there a reason you're using mpich2 instead of OpenMPI or LAM?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up mpich's hosts file, and give it a way to start jobs on other hosts.  e.g. with rsh and `/etc/hosts.equiv` in a trusted network environment.

For testing only, I think there's a local-host-only way to run mpich.
Oh, but maybe not enabled by default:
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=301551

Sorry I can't remember the tricks... It's been too long.